# YSlow: Incorrect number of HTTP requests?

Tags: performance-testing, yslow

A page I'm looking at optimising has around 83-87 HTTP requests as measured by Chrome dev tools and WebPageTest (the exact number is slightly variable depending on affiliate libraries).

However, the YSlow Chrome extension claims there are only 51 requests. Likewise, YSlow run from ShowSlow is showing 60 requests.

The difference between YSlow measures aside, it does look like YSlow is measuring the number of HTTP requests incorrectly, and thus my faith in the recommendations and grade is not good.

The page in question does load some components post-onload (which [YSlow doesn't measure](http://yslow.org/faq/#faq_ajax)), but there are only 10 components loaded post-load (which doesn't account for the 20-30 anomaly with other tools).

Anyone know why this might be happening, or indeed provide some suggestions on how to debug or diagnose?

Comment: Usually the count should be pretty close, with the caveats like you mentioned of 3rd-party libraries, ads, etc. Different browsers can also have a different number of requests, but within one browser (YSlow Chrome vs Chrome devtools) it should be close. Do you have a public example URL you could share?

Comment: As an example: http://www.bally.co.uk. WebPageTest reports 76 requests (49 onload), but YSlow reports 57 requests...

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the link you suggested (bally.co.uk) to compare YSlow with WebPageTest. YSlow reported 56 components and WebPageTest 76. Here's the breakout:

- Doc/html: yslow 1, wpt 3, diff: 2 0-byte files
- Javascript: yslow 37, wpt 39, diff: 2 0-byte files
- CSS: yslow 5, wpt 5
- Images: yslow 12, wpt 19, diff: 7 1x1 beacon gifs
- Favicon: yslow 1, wpt 1
- JSON: yslow 0, wpt 7, diff: 7 dynamically loaded
- Font: yslow 0, wpt 2, diff: 2 dynamically loaded

My conclusion goes back to the link you provided to the YSlow FAQ. The differences all seem to be dynamic requests that are either 0-byte or very small (like the 1x1 gifs). I think it's due to the combined DOM and network sniffing approach that YSlow takes.

Also if I compare the total size loaded for the first view, they are very close to each other:

- YSlow: 1,683 KB
- WebPageTest: 1,711 KB